# A strange behavior of the ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting

I am plotting this:

```
ParametricPlot[{(Sin[φ/2]^2*Sin[φ])/Cos[(3 φ)/2], Sin[φ/2]^2/(
  1 + 2 Sin[φ/2])}, {φ, 0, π/3},AspectRatio -> 0.7]
```

and see this:

[image]

Then I do the following:

```
lst=Table[{(Sin[φ/2]^2*Sin[φ])/Cos[(3 φ)/2], Sin[φ/2]^2/(
      1 + 2 Sin[φ/2])}, {φ, 0, π/3,0.02}, AspectRatio -> 0.7];

ListPlot[lst, PlotRange -> {0, 0.12}]
```

and get this, as expected:

[image]

What' the matter?

I have Mma 11.3 on Win7

Later edit: I tried the advice of @J. M. is slightly pensive. That's what I see:

[image]

Comment: Try adding the options `Axes -> None, PlotRange -> All`.

Comment: @J. M. is slightly pensive I tried and get something very strange, please see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ParametricPlot[{(Sin[\[CurlyPhi]/2]^2*Sin[\[CurlyPhi]])/
Cos[(3 \[CurlyPhi])/2], 
Sin[\[CurlyPhi]/2]^2/(1 + 2 Sin[\[CurlyPhi]/2])}, 
{\[CurlyPhi],0.001, \[Pi]/3 - 0.001}, AspectRatio -> 0.7]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it works now. Do you see, what's the matter? Why it does not like the strict phi=0 and phi=Pi/3?

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch Mathematica seems to have problems at `\[CurlyPhi]->Pi/3`. If you change the  plotrange `ParametricPlot[{(Sin[\[CurlyPhi]/2]^2*Sin[\[CurlyPhi]])/
   Cos[(3 \[CurlyPhi])/2], 
  Sin[\[CurlyPhi]/2]^2/(1 + 2 Sin[\[CurlyPhi]/2])}, {\[CurlyPhi], 
  0, \[Pi]/2}, AspectRatio -> 0.7]` everything works fine...

Comment: Thank you, I understand.

Answer (score 2):

At $\frac{\pi}{3}$ you get `1/0`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And `ParametricPlot` could not handle it. tried `Exclusions` option but it did not help.

Another possible option is to filter these problem points out manually

```
f[φ_: _?NumericQ] := 
  If[φ == Pi/3, {Nothing}, {(Sin[φ/2]^2*Sin[φ])/Cos[(3 φ)/2],Sin[φ/2]^2/(1 + 2 Sin[φ/2])}];
ParametricPlot[f[φ], {φ, 0, π/3}, AspectRatio -> 0.7]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, I see